# Jekyll conditionally render file based on JS url param

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll

I'm trying to conditionally render an include file in my Jekyll application in production mode (compiled) based on whether a URL param is included in my URL so I can change what file has been loaded.

I need to do this with JS, since JS is what'll be accepting the params, but I can't figure out how Jekyll would even know, I'm wondering if there's a plugin for JEKYLL or something similar that could work.

In my URL, e.g: https://example.com/page I'll specify some `mode` param, which I then want to decide what file to show.

```html
<div>

  <!-- Default -->
  {% include_relative includes/form/form.html %}

  <!--
    If URL param 'mode' is set
  -->
  {% include_relative includes/form/form_lookup.html %}
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jekyll generates static websites, so it produces everything before even knowing what JS tells the page. For this kind of dynamic behavior you can't use Jekyll itself. There are some workarounds:

- You could generate two separate pages and return one or another based on the parameter of your URL.
- Generate a single page whith both forms included and an embedded script that hides one or another depending on the value set from javascript:

```html
<script>
  // Check the URL parameter
  check_mode(){
    // See tutorial below
  }
  // Display one or another
  show_form(x){
    if(x == "formA"){
      document.getElementById("formB").style.display = "none"
    }else if(x == "formB"){
      document.getElementById("formA").style.display = "none"
    }
    document.getElementById(x).style.display = "initial" // or whatever visible
  }

if(check_mode())
  show_form("formA")
else
  show_form("formB")
</script>

<div>

  <!-- Default -->
  <div id="formA">
    {% include_relative includes/form/form.html %}
  </div>

  <!--
    If URL param 'mode' is set
  -->
  <div id="formB">
    {% include_relative includes/form/form_lookup.html %}
  </div>
</div>
```

It's true that you are sending both forms and that's not the most efficient use of bandwith and browser memory, but worst things happen on the web. Also, although it is not the cleanest way, I think is enough to point you in some direction, given the scope of the question.

---

[Get the URL parameters from Javascript](https://html-online.com/articles/get-url-parameters-javascript/).